# How to Check for Available Channels In A List<>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button

I am a C++ developer and I recently shifted to C#. I am working on a wpf app where I have to dynamically generate button, labels and textbox. Along with dynamically generating them, I have made sure only those channels must be displayed which are available by maintaining a bool available property. Here is the code:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource booltovisibility}}">          

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ChannelName}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding VoltageText}" PreviewTextInput="VoltageBox_PreviewTextInput"  />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Set" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding VoltageCommand}" />
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding CurrentText}" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="3" Content="On" Command="{Binding VoltageToggleCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" />
</Grid>

    <Button Content="Refresh All" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding Path=RefreshAllButtonCommand}" Name="RefreshAllBtn" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel> channelList = null;
public ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel> bavaria1Channels = new ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel>
    {
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__MAIN", IsAvailable = true, ID = 1},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__IO", IsAvailable = true, ID = 2},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__CODEC", IsAvailable = true, ID = 3},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__LDO", IsAvailable = true, ID = 4},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__AMP", IsAvailable = true, ID = 5},   
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 6}, 
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 7}, 
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 8}, 
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 9}, 
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 10}, 
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 11}, 
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 12}, 
    };        

    public VoltageViewModel()
    {
        channelList = new ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel>();
        channelList = bavaria1Channels;         

    }
public ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel> VoltageChannelList
    {
        get 
        { 
            return channelList; 
        }

        set
        { 
            channelList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChannelList");
        }
    }

void RefreshAllClick()
{
    //Here I want to check if channel are available or not. If yes then execute few statements.
}
```

**Model Class:**

```
private string mChannelName;
    public string ChannelName
    {
        get
        {
            return mChannelName;
        }
        set
        {
            mChannelName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChannelName");
        }
    }

    private bool mIsAvailable;
    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get
        {
            return mIsAvailable;
        }
        set
        {
            mIsAvailable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsAvailable");
        }
    }

    double voltageText;
    public double VoltageText
    {
        get
        {
            return voltageText;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value > 5.0D || value < 0.0D)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            voltageText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VoltageText");
        }
    }

    string currentText = "0";
    public string CurrentText
    {
        get
        {
            return currentText + " V";                
        }

        set
        {
            currentText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentText");
        }
    }          

    int index ;
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return index;
        }

        set
        {
            index = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
```

Thus if you notice in my `Bavaria1 Channel` you will find few channels are available(true) and few are false. Thus on startup it displays only the Available channels. Thus using booltovisibility class I am able to set the visibility in my grid and display accordingly Now here is what I want to achieve:

When I click `RefreshAll` Button, a method called `RefreshAll_Click()` is triggered and I want to check in a `if` condition which channels are available. If yes then execute few statements. I had done this in C++ as follows:

```
if(m_voltageChannels[channel].available) // Here channel is 12 as you can notice in bavaria1 list
{
    cmd = (0x8400 | (channel & 0xFF));  

    String OldValue = m_labelCurrentVoltage[channel]->getText();
            //Some Code
    }
```

How can I achieve this? :)

Comment: you wanna check is there any channel available?

Comment: @CuongLe: I want to check if there is any channel available. If yes then execute few statements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `foreach` loop, or linq.  Since you're starting out in C#, here's the foreach approach:

```
void RefreshAllClick() 
{
    foreach (var channel in channelList)
        if (channel.IsAvailable)
            //some code here 
}
```

Or, since `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IList<T>`, you can index into the collection, as in your C++ code:

```
if (channelList[channel].IsAvailable)
    //some code here
```

If you just need a boolean that is true iff at least one channel is available, linq is best:

```
var anyChannelIsAvailable = channelList.Any(c => c.IsAvailable);
```

Moved from my previous (now deleted) comment, here's some unsolicited further advice:

You should remove the line `channelList = new ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel>();`, since you're immediately discarding that object by reassigning the reference in the next line (`channelList = bavaria1Channels;`).  In fact, you don't need `bavaria1Channels` (nor the constructor) at all; you can just declare and initialize `channelList` with the collection initializer expression, like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel> channelList = new ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel>    
{    
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__MAIN", IsAvailable = true, ID = 1},    
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__IO", IsAvailable = true, ID = 2},    
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__CODEC", IsAvailable = true, ID = 3},    
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__LDO", IsAvailable = true, ID = 4},    
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__AMP", IsAvailable = true, ID = 5},       
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 6},     
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 7},     
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 8},     
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 9},     
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 10},     
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 11},     
     new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, ID = 12},     
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (bavaria1Channels.Any(c => c.IsAvailable)) //Any channel available
{
    //Execute some code :)
}
```